# Multi-language syntax highlighting in Emacs

Tags: python, sql, emacs

Say I have code from multiple languages in a single buffer, can I have emacs syntax highlight each snippet according to its corresponding language?

For example, the following code is part of a python script, but it contains SQL code:

```
import psycopg2 as pg
import pandas.io.sql as psql

# Some SQL code:
my_query ='''
select count(distinct s.object_uid) 
from dx.dx_segment as s;
'''
# end of SQL code

dataframe = psql.frame_query(my_query, connection)
```

It would be great to have the SQL part highlighted as SQL syntax, while the rest of the file highlighted as Python.

Is this possible in Emacs? Any way to hint to Emacs what highlighter to use, perhaps taking advantage of the comments?

Comment: Cross-referencing with http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes for anyone looking for options.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I'm using some SQL in C, I have a system using MMM-Mode; wrapping the required statement in a set of comments,

```
/* SQL */
```

and

```
/* #SQL */
```

the following will give me SQL syntax highlighting:

```lisp
 (require 'mmm-mode)
 (set-face-background 'mmm-default-submode-face nil)

 (mmm-add-classes
  '((embedded-sql
     :submode sql-mode
     :front "/* SQL */"
     :back "/* #SQL */")))

 (mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'c-mode "*.c" 'c-sql)
 (setq mmm-never-modes
               (append '(ediff-mode) '(text-mode) mmm-never-modes))
```

I can then use the mmm-ify-by-class to apply the c-sql class - Perhaps you can do similar in Python?

For me, the following lisp allows Emacs to see the sample SQL string in the sample python as SQL (Light gray background indicates where MMM mode is active)

[image]

(Modified again to allow single line statements)

```lisp
(require 'mmm-mode)

(mmm-add-classes
 '((python-sql
    :submode sql-mode
    :face mmm-code-submode-face
    :front "# SQL\\(\n\\|\t\\)*\\(\[ -_A-Z0-9\]+\\)\\(\[ =\]\\)\\(\"\"\"\\|'''\\)"
    :back "\\(\"\"\"\\|'''\\)\\( \\|\t\\|\n\\)*\\# /SQL")))

(mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'python-mode "*.py" 'python-sql)
```

Comment: Thanks @Orpheus. If I were to change this for a  Python + SQL combination, I presume I could wrap up my SQL code lines in a Python wrapper with `# /* SQL */` and `# /* #SQL */` since Python comments start with `#`. What else should I change from your example to adapt it to Python? What does the line `(mmm-add-mode-ext-class 'c-mode "*.c" 'c-sql)` tell `mmm-mode` to do?

Comment: The choice of tag value is simply something that is unlikely to be used for any other purpose, and follows the language rules - in the case of Python, a combination of `# SQL` and `# /SQL` perhaps? The `mmm-add-mode-ext-class` simply means parse any file matching the *.c regexp and apply the c-mode major mode, and the user-defined c-sql mode (For an explination, try `C-h f mmm-add-mode-ext-class`; hope that helps

Comment: Thanks - I am unable to make this work. I am using Emacs 24.3, with the latest version of `python-mode` (just pulled from the repository) and the latest version from `mmm-mode` (package installation from MELPA, with version `20140211`). Any thoughts on how to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I (recently) got it working:

1. Specify the tags *within* the SQL string variable--otherwise python-mode just considers it all one string and formats it accordingly.
2. This means the tags should start with `--` in order to not interfere with the SQL itself.
3. Run `(mmm-ify-by-class 'python-sql)` within the SQL region I wanted highlighted. mmm-mode must be enabled before you do this. Orpheus's solution mentions this but I did not realize what they were saying at first.